# Assume $f$ is continuous with period $T$. Prove for every $n \in \Bbb N~ \exists x \in [0, T]$ such that $f(x) = f(x + \frac Tn)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, periodic-functions

I tried using another function $g(x) = f(x + T/n) - f(x)$, and found that
$g(0) + g(T/n) + ... g(T(n-1)/n) = 0$, but I don't know where to go from there. Any ideas on how prove this?

Comment: As stated this is false.  Do you also know that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention, f is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is  no such $x$ then  $f(x+T/n)-f(x)$ is always positive or always negative. Suppose it is always positive. Then $$0=f(T)-f(0)=[f(\frac {nT} n)-f(\frac {(n-1) T)} n]$$ $$+[f(\frac {(n-1)T} n)-f(\frac {(n-2)T} n)]+...+[f(\frac T n)-f(0)]>0,$$ a contradiction.  The other case is similar.